# How to find unused columns in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to remove unused fields to improve clarity and possibly to improve performance. But first I have to find out the unused fields in SQL Server 2008R2. Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Unused by what? views? applications? SSIS packages? everything? Someone might have a SQL script sitting somewhere that you'll never know about until they try to use. Your bet bet is to run some auditing for a few months.

Answer (score 0):

This task isn't simple at all, but you can start with the following:

- Query the `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` system view.
- Query the `sys.objects` system view, filtering by `OBJECT_DEFINITION(O.object_id) LIKE '%YourColumnName%'`. This will list all objects that have that column in it's code, will also list them if they are commented o partially written (LIKE).
- Use the SQL Profiler to capture daily traffic over a decent amount of time depending on your system and review the requests for containing your columns.

Unfortunately, if your column names are common words (like person, date, id, etc), the 2nd and 3rd methods will yield a lot of code to review.

Also keep in mind that if you execute dynamic SQL against those tables, it might be very hard to catch it.